# Implement clear button for "The following tags" in question filter

Tags: support, feature-request, questions, filtering

In the question filter, we may set search attributes in "The following tags". After querying for "My watched tags", the area below "The following tags" gets filled with my watched tags. That's nice, but an option of clearing this field again is missing. This gets a little annoying when I want to search for different tags or a single tag afterwards. For example in my case, when I want to search for the original [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag again, I have to click away seventeen other tags. (I use an updated Firefox browser on a Windows 7 machine as well as on an Ubuntu 18.04, if that is relevant.)

Is it possible to implement some reset or clear button?

[image]